# node Js : API post 400 bad request

Tags: node.js

this is my first project in node js and i created an API that have get, delete, update, and post.
i tested GET and response 200 ok but POST is 400 bad request i don't know why ...
i tested this in postman and vue js too but same result

below is my code in nodeJs:
can someone please tell me what is the problem?

thanks in advance

```js
//question.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const questionSchema = new Schema({
  questionTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  is_solver_selected : {
    type: Boolean,
    default : false,
  },
  reviewed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default : false,
  },
  question_file_path: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  solutions : [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:"Solution",
      default : []
    }
  ],
  owner : {
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : "User",
    required : true
  },
  categories : [{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : "Category",
    required : true
  }],
  answered: {
    type: Boolean,
    default : false,
  },
  budget : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  }
}, { timestamps: true });

const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
module.exports = Question;
```

```js
//questionApiController

const Category = require('../models/category');
const Question = require('../models/question');
const User = require('../models/user');
const  validators  = require('../validators');

let questionApiController = {

    
  // Get a single question

  get_question : async (req , res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    try {
        const question = await Question.findById(id,(err, question) => {
          
          if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : err});
          
          res.status(200).json({response : question})
      }).populate('owner', 'username').populate('categories').populate({
        path : "solutions",
        populate : {path : "solver_candidate" , select : "username"}});
  
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Get all the questions

  get_questions: async (req , res) => {
    try {
      const questions = await Question.find((err, questions) => {
          
        if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : err});
        
        res.status(200).json({response : questions})
        
    }).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).populate('owner', 'username').populate('categories').populate({
      path : "solutions",
      populate : {path : "solver_candidate" , select : "username"}});
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Create a question
  
  create_question : async (req , res) => {

    const {error} = validators.postQuestionValidation(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).json({ "response" : error.details[0].message})

    try {
      const question = await new Question(req.body);

      
      
      
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.owner)
      .then(result => {
        result.questions.push(question._id)
        result.save((err, categories) => {
          
          if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : {error : err , explanation : " Error binding to the user !"}});
          
      });

      })
      .catch(err => {
      
      res.status(400).json({response: err });
    });


    req.body.categories.forEach(element => {
      Category.findById(element).then(result => {
        
      }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json({response : err });
      })
    })



    question.save((err, question) => {
          
      if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : err});
      
      res.status(200).json({response : " Question created Successfully"})
      
  });

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Delete question

  delete_question : async (req , res) => {

    const id = req.params.id;

    var questionExist = false;
    var userId ;

    const question = await Question.findById(id).then(result => {
      questionExist = true;
      userId = result.owner;
    }).catch(err => {
      questionExist = false;
      res.status(400).json({response : err });
    });

    

    if(questionExist){
      try {
        Question.findByIdAndRemove(id ,(err, question) => {
          // As always, handle any potential errors:
          if (err) return res.json({response : err});
          // We'll create a simple object to send back with a message and the id of the document that was removed
          // You can really do this however you want, though.
          const response = {
              message: "Question successfully deleted",
              id: question._id
          };
          return res.status(200).json({response : response });
      });
  
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId)
          .then(result => {
            
            let pos = result.questions.indexOf(question._id);
            result.questions.splice(pos,1);
            result.save((err, categories) => {
            
              if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : {error : err , explanation : "Error binding unbinding from the user"}});
              
          });
  
          })
          .catch(err => {
          
          res.json({response: err });
        });
  
      } catch (err) {
          res.status(400).json(err);
      }
    }

    else {

      return res.status(400).send( { "response" : "A question with that id was not find."});
    }    

  },

  // Update question

  update_question : async (req , res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Question.findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body,
      function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({response : err});
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({response : "Question Updated"}); 
            console.log(result);
          }
        })
  },

  bind_question_to_solver : async (req , res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Question.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{
        solver : req.body.solver ,
        response_file_path : req.body.response_file_path},function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({response : err});
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({response : "Question Bind to Solver"});
            //Update the user solver by adding the question id in its quesion array1  
            console.log(result);
          }
        })
  },

  // Get question's questions

  get_question_categories : async (req , res) => {

    const id = req.params.id;
    try {
      const question_categories = await Question.findById(id).populate("categories")
      console.log(question_categories)
      res.json(question_categories)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
        res.json(err);
    }
  }


}


module.exports = questionApiController
```

```js
//question controller 

const Question = require('../models/question');

const question_index = (req, res) => {
  Question.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .then(result => {
      res.render('index', { questions: result, title: 'All questions' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const question_details = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Question.findById(id)
    .then(result => {
      res.render('details', { question: result, title: 'Question Details' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.render('404', { title: 'Question not found' });
    });
}

const question_create_get = (req, res) => {
  res.render('create', { title: 'Create a new question' });
}

const question_create_post = (req, res) => {
  const question = new Question(req.body);
  question.save()
    .then(result => {
      res.redirect('/questions');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const question_delete = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Question.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(result => {
      res.json({ redirect: '/questions' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = {
  question_index, 
  question_details, 
  question_create_get, 
  question_create_post, 
  question_delete
}
```

sent request:

Post http://localhost:9000/questions/api/add
content-type: application/json

{
"description": "d",
"questionTitle": "ddd",
"categories":"ddd",
"question_file_path":"d.pdf",
"budget":"d",
"owner":"bla",

}

`error message': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 160
at JSON.parse ()
at parse (C:\Users\saad\Desktop\APi-master-nodejs\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
at C:\Users\saad\Desktop\APi-master-nodejs\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\saad\Desktop\APi-master-nodejs\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (C:\Users\saad\Desktop\APi-master-nodejs\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\saad\Desktop\APi-master-nodejs\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

update:
tested on vue js app console logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlJeh.png)

Comment: You are the one handling the status code and statuses go check the route and log it to find the issue .

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please share the request that you are sending and the function that handles the request. Also, share the error message if you see it in the terminal.

Comment: @David question edited please take a look

Answer (score 0):

based on your updated post, i would start to fix the provided json. because as the response says, it is invalid. JSON does not have trailing comma at the end of the last entry.

```
{ "description": "d", "questionTitle": "ddd", "categories":"ddd", "question_file_path":"d.pdf", "budget":"d", "owner":"bla"}
```

would be fine.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tested my API on real vue js web application but same problem occurred please check the updated question above

Answer (score 0):

Check [why-body-parser-json-is-not-working-showing-syntaxerror-unexpected-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257048/why-body-parser-json-is-not-working-showing-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) post, you have a similar problem.

You are sending `,` symbol after last field in the json object which is not expected by the `body-parser` when you are sending `content-type: application/json`

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tested my API on real vue js web application but same problem occurred please check the updated question above

Answer (score 0):

In `questionSchema` you have a field called `categories` which must be an array of `ObjectId`s but you are sending a `string` in the request body

```
  categories : [{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : "Category",
    required : true
  }],
```

Comment: please check the image above, i tested this API on real working vue js app and it shows the same problem :/

Comment: this screenshot doesn't help, it displays the wrong information. your console log displays an object, not the actual posted data. i bet your json string is still invalid, for whatever reason. take a look at the raw posted data (also a viewable in the devtools panel)